# How to insert multidimensional list into sqlite db

Tags: python, list, sqlite, binding

I need to insert list like this

```
 list = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]
```

so I unpack it and try to insert it into db

```
 a,b,c,d = list

 db.execute("INSERT INTO show (titolo,stagioni,clima,temperature) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(a,b,c,d))
 db.commit()
```

but It returns this error

> exception=InterfaceError('Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.')>

I tried even [list]

any help , thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to match the exact signature of list here.

```py
a, b, c, d = lst
# a -> ['1']
# b -> ['2']
# c -> ['3']
# d -> ['4']

([a], [b], [c], [d]) = lst
# a -> '1'
# b -> '2'
# c -> '3'
# d -> '4'
```

---

One more option is to use `itertools.chain`

```py
from itertools import chain
a, b, c, d = chain.from_iterable(lst)
# a -> '1'
# b -> '2'
# c -> '3'
# d -> '4'
```